# Why are my records duplicated when writing them to a file?

Tags: unity, file

I am writing data to a file every two seconds. I used InvokeRepeating and everything is Ok except that every record is saved 3 times in the file:

```
void Start(){
    File.WriteAllText(filePath_users, "timestamp" + "," + "id" + "," + "pos" + "," + "rot" + System.Environment.NewLine);
    InvokeRepeating("SaveUsersTracking", 1.0f, 2.0f);
}

void SaveUsersTracking(){
    //save this data every two seconds...
    File.AppendAllText(filePath_users, System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "," + "U1" + "," + "(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8)" + "," + "(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)" + System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

My results look like:

```
timestamp,id,pos,rot
4/20/2019 8:09:47 PM,U1,(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8),(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)
4/20/2019 8:09:47 PM,U1,(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8),(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)//I don't need this record
4/20/2019 8:09:47 PM,U1,(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8),(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)//I don't need this record
4/20/2019 8:09:49 PM,U1,(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8),(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)
4/20/2019 8:09:49 PM,U1,(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8),(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)//I don't need this record
4/20/2019 8:09:49 PM,U1,(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8),(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)//I don't need this record
4/20/2019 8:09:51 PM,U1,(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8),(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)
4/20/2019 8:09:51 PM,U1,(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8),(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)//I don't need this record
4/20/2019 8:09:51 PM,U1,(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8),(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)//I don't need this record
```

Comment: Could there be three instances of this MonoBehaviour active in the scene?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `2.0f` from the end of `InvokeRepeating` 
The second argument is a repeat rate so it is saving it 3 times (the executed plus the 2 repeats).

```
void Start(){
    File.WriteAllText(filePath_users, "timestamp" + "," + "id" + "," + "pos" + "," + "rot" + System.Environment.NewLine);
    InvokeRepeating("SaveUsersTracking", 1.0f);
}

void SaveUsersTracking(){
    //save this data every two seconds...
    File.AppendAllText(filePath_users, System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "," + "U1" + "," + "(-2.7, 1.3, -1.8)" + "," + "(0.2, -0.7, 0.2)" + System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: A good answer is one which doesn't just fix the mistake but also tells people how to avoid that mistake in the future by explaining them what they misunderstood. Can you explain *why* this solves the problem?

Comment: edited answer to better explain what the mistake was.